# meta property: title - does not displaying the correct content on Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

After adding meta property, the specific page that I want to share on Facebook, is not displaying the correct content/ text/ wording.

For example I want to share a contact page and this is its meta tags:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500" />

<!-- standard meta content -->
<meta name="description" content="Sample Website is a ..." />
<meta name="keywords" content="..." />

<!-- social meta content -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Contact | Sample Website">
<meta property="og:description" content="Sample Website is a ....">
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=...">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="Sample Website is a ...">

<title>Contact | Sample Website</title>
```

So I expect that the wording for this page is:

```
Contact | Sample Website
```

But on Facebook news feed, it is displaying the general content/ wording about the Sample Website, e.g.:

```
Sample Website | A ....
```

This content is coming from the home page of this Sample Website:

```html
<title>Sample Website | A ....</title>
```

Any ideas why?

How can I display the specific content of the page I want to share, e.g. Contact page?

**NOTES:** it seems it works OK on Twitter, LinkedIn, but not Facebook.

Comment: Most likely because og:url is pointing to the homepage and not the specific page. But you can use Facebook share debugger to verify. Or tell us which URL you are trying to share

Comment: @WizKid you are right. my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi once you or anyone else enter a URL on faceBook , Facebook creates its preview in its database, and do not update it unless you ask facebook to udpate.

So if you entered the links before updating the meta property then go here and update your link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ I hope this helps.

After you go to the Debug link in Facebook enter the URL which you are trying to fix, Then you can see when facebook scraped that URL , click scrape again and refresh page i hope it will fix problem. Then post your URL again in post it will fetch new data.